# Passing data between two table views

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

What I am trying to do is .. i want to pass the data between two table views.

In my root view controller I am using an array and then populating it for the RootViewController and in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method I am doing this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        self.schedule.title = @"Show1";
        NSLog(@"SCHEDULE CONTROLLER TITLE = %@", schedule.title);
        NSLog(@"FIRST ROW ");
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        self.schedule.title = @"Show2";
        NSLog(@"SECOND ROW");
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 2){
        self.schedule.title = @"Show3";
        NSLog(@"THIRD ROW");
    }

    schedule = [[ScheduleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScheduleViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:schedule animated:YES];
```

schedule is another table view so.. what I am doing is I am comparing the titile of schedule  to decide the contents of schedule table view, but some how it is not getting the data.

here is `ViewDidLoad` method of schedule view:

```
 [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self.title isEqualToString:@"Show1"])
    {
        showSchedule = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"SUNDAY",@"MONDAY",@"TUESDAY" , nil];
    }
    if ([self.title isEqualToString:@"Show2"])
    {
        showSchedule = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"WEDNESDAY",@"THURSDAY",@"FRIDAY" , nil];
    }else {
        showSchedule = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"SATURDAY", nil];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

The `self.title` is returning null and therefore it goes into the else loop at the end.
 Any ideas what I am doing wrong here.. ?

Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: You appear to be setting the `title` property before you create `schedule`.

Comment: whoa...!! thanks for pointing that out Phillip Mills. It was real silly missing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your title after alloc the controller

```
NSString *titleOfTableVC ;

if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    titleOfTableVC = @"Show1";
    NSLog(@"SCHEDULE CONTROLLER TITLE = %@", titleOfTableVC );
    NSLog(@"FIRST ROW ");
}
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    titleOfTableVC = @"Show2";
    NSLog(@"SECOND ROW");
}
if(indexPath.row == 2){
    titleOfTableVC = @"Show3";
    NSLog(@"THIRD ROW");
}

schedule = [[ScheduleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScheduleViewController" bundle:nil];
schedule.title =  titleOfTableVC ;    
[self.navigationController pushViewController:schedule animated:YES];
```

Hope this will make u understand

Comment: Abhishek: Yes. I was using the title property before creating the schedule table view. It works fine now..! 
Thanks a lot..! :)

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
if ([self.title isEqualToString:@"Show1"])
     {
```

replace this line.

```
if ([ self.navigationItem.title isEqualToString:@"Show1"])
   {
```

Then try

Comment: Ayaz: Thanks a lot.. i got it solved. I was missing that I am using the self.title before creating the schedule table view. 
It works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding title before allocing the view...